# How do I track actions that the user takes on a different website?

Tags: javascript

I have seen websites such as google and facebook do this and I've done some search but honestly I'm not sure what I should be looking for.

When these websites send confirmation codes to your email in order to verify your account, sometimes the confirmation is triggered before you even enter the code. I've also seen it happening on mobile with confirmation codes being sent via SMS. As soon as the SMS is received, the app asking for the confirmation code detects it and accepts the confirmation without the user having to input the code.

How do these websites track what is happening on a different website/app?

Comment: For emails, simple javascript in embedded html.  For SMS not possible.

Answer (score 0):

The page that's waiting for the code usually is polling a service in some way.  Common methods include Server-Sent Events and Web Sockets.

When the user becomes authorized through an action elsewhere, server-side, a message is sent indicating the waiting client to try again, now that authorization should be allowed.

In the SMS case, apps used to get read access to your messages and would be notified this way.  This is less common now, due to privacy concerns.